# How to decode eval( gzinflate( base64_decode(

Tags: php

I have this code injected in my site. How can I decode the trailing string? I need to know what happened and what is the code behind it.

Comment: Is this some kind of WordPress footer? Then: http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php

Comment: Be careful using `eval()` when you don't know what's in it. Start from the innermost function call until you get clear text

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should output the code that would be executed by `eval()`:

```
<?php
echo gzinflate( base64_decode( /* insert code */ ));
?>
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks lshtar,
It did not display the contained text though.
I beileve it's part of the template I took for the WP site. I will have to rewrite it, keeping the credits, but something there is fishy.

Comment: Well, it should be exactly what php would execute. However its not failed HTML or such, so you should look at the source of your website to see it. Hope this helps.

Comment: They nest the code within decode after decode.  I just looked at one the was 28 iterations deep before you reached the actual code.  Here is a site that will run through the entire set and give you the resulting code http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/

Answer (score 9):

I use this to remove the nasty code injected in all my PHP files from public_html folder:

```
find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/<?.*eval(gzinflate(base64.*?>/ d' '{}' \; -print
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [eval gzinflate base64 decoder](http://www.base64online.com)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.