# Can PHP load a encrypted file?

Tags: php

For example, I would like to:

```
require('encrypted.php')
```

"encrypted.php" contains php code that was encrypted with base64, and I have the key to decrypt it. Is there a way to first decrypt the file and then just load the decrypted code into PHP?

Comment: base64 is encoding, not encryption.

Comment: Encrypted with `base64`... is this a joke?  You have the key to decrypt it?  You realize base64 is not an encryption method, right?  It is simple encoding, and no key is required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701291/how-to-decode-eval-gzinflate-base64-decode

Comment: base64 or not is not important, I just made up the scenario. The main question I'm asking is about loading a encrypted file into PHP that I have the key to decrypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first way that jumps to mind is:

```
eval("?".">".base64_decode(file_get_contents("encrypted.php"))."<"."?php");
```

However that's probably not a good idea (evil eval).

Why have you encrypted a PHP file anyway? Nobody can see the source code unless you mess around with things.

Comment: +1 Forgot about closing the existing open `<?php ?>`. Shows how often I would want or need to `eval()` a file...

Comment: Ha ha this looks like a virus so much.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to load the file's contents with `file_get_contents()` or similar, then call `base64_decode()` on it and `eval()` it as PHP.  Only do this if you are certain of the contents of the file and you trust its source.

```
// Only do this is the file is trusted!!!
$phpcode = base64_decode(file_get_contents("trusted_encoded_file.php"));
eval($phpcode);
```

**Note:** See @Kolink's implementation if the encoded file contains `<?php ?>` open/close tags.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any key to decode base64 data , use [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking. base64 or not is not important, I just made up the scenario. The main question I'm asking is about loading a encrypted file into PHP that I have the key to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

It is not professional solution, but take  look at this : http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/