# What does this script do?

Tags: php

I have a website where users can upload files to share with others. But first I need to verify them.
Lately someone uploaded a .php file with the following commands:

```
‰PNG

<?php
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("very large strings of characters")));

?>
```

I figured it might be harmful, so I didnt open it.

Does anyone have any idea what it does?

Comment: It does something malicious. Replace `eval` with `echo` and take a look. Or at least post the actual string of characters so we can decode it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode eval( gzinflate( base64_decode(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701291/how-to-decode-eval-gzinflate-base64-decode)

Comment: Looking at stackoverflow site I am abashed to see how many people have no idea of the site called google

Comment: I added the string above

Comment: @Your Common Sense, I did try google first but without findind what im looking for. Dont you think that is one of the purposes of this site?

Comment: I posted the code here: http://www.thecodekeepers.com/unknown_script.txt
It is a text file, but I dont know if its harmless in that format so be careful. I would appreciate opinions about the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the attacker's code was base64 encoded and gzipped.

So first the code is decoded from base64 encoding, and then it is unzipped basically until a string of code.

And then eval is called on the resulting string, which will execute the code that has been decoded and unzipped.

But without seeing what code gets generated, it is hard to say what it will do when the code is run.

---

I decoded the encoded text. Using the following approach

**(I guess writing to file was a bad idea now that I think of it. Mainly if you're on Windows. I guess it is a bit safer on Linux with the execute bit turned off. So I was kind of lucky in this case!)**

```
<?php
$test = gzinflate(base64_decode("encoded_text"));
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $test);
fclose($fh);
```

I wrote the output to file just in case there was some random html or javascript that could infect my computer if I just echoed it to my browser. That may be why you got an anti-virus warning.

I'm not sure what it does yet.

---

Just skimming through the code, which is like 4,750 lines of code, it seems like it sets up Basic Auth. And then there's a lot of database functions and some basic html interface. This in PHP. There's also some perl too. Near the end.

Basically what it seems to do is this: Every page where that image is displayed it will output parts of that code and execute it along with your code, and it will try to get input data, or try to find session data and or database values.

Then other parts of the code basically create an admin interface when the url is visited like this: url?admin=1, which brings up a Basic Auth authentication. And then there is an simple interface phpmyadmin like interface where the user can try out different queries and gather out metadata about your db. Probably other stuff run to exec, etc too.

I could be wrong, but that's the gist I get from going through the code.

Comment: Could you please post the code on the contact page of the website I posted in my question

Comment: Sure, I'll try to send. Hopefully your form does not have character limit. Long script.

Comment: Anyway I sent it. Hopefully it got through.

Comment: I got the email, but it wouldnt open "No response from subprocess with exit signal: 0" I have windows so I will follow your adivice and not do what you did. If you can upload it somewhere and give me the link I would appreciate it, or if you want I can give you my email to send it to me directly

Comment: Never mind Gohn67, I took the risk myself and got the code. I find this very interesting. I know nothing about the hacking world.

Answer (score 3):

nobody can tell you, just do

```
<?php echo gzinflate(base64_decode("very large strings of characters")) ?>
```

to see what it **would** do....

edit: well now that you've posted the whole string i decoded it and pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/BubDTsa0)

Comment: My anti virus gave me this alert:

The following threat was encountered:

The requested object is INFECTED with the following viruses: Backdoor.PHP.Rst.bl

Comment: What if there is some XSS code in there? Maybe the php will come out as text. But if there is js and html and image links, those will be outputted. Probably why he got the anti-virus warning. Although I admit my suggestion to write to file and then view it was probably stupider. I was lucky though.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine the only thing you need to take care is the long string that is encrypted

```
< ?php eval(gzinflate(base64_decode("very large strings of characters")));
```

for the reference of this kind of the statement you can refer to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php