# What does this PHP code do?? I think it's to crash a PHP server

Tags: php

Trying to help a friend with a website and I came across this code in one of his files:

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(rawurldecode('XVe3zsawEXucJPDg3hBkcO%2B9ewncey%2Bf7afPP0ebIAEHkUceVd3Z%2BM88OyoC%2B29ZFUtZ%2FbP5rrlYpnWvjuP%2Fjv5Rqb9wpBBv%2Bd6vlSi1qYZEnOoH6Zjfebms%2FcYOv3Lg87dPPvPCrM1Oh0MItF2rem30aAheEYLoweyWz9pabTXt4z5eblWb6Vnrf7l50fAA1GBm1JqiGBSSiAfZzBR%2BpjTHp3Q21QgBOusN2sgW1sU46MPDqtOvinm4CEmotPiRRnPYoVUDtpazOjRHg82MXwQTYBzxRXrFAJiY1Sn1uEDuwab0boAzNgizZxb4bIqT2qQoyH4NDzEpFq05E3wRN5oaeF2zFsApoLXXe%2FlMWJRmM2m0%2FA1pLsxo3oq9yx2tA%2FQPg3sAHOsABK44L%2FeAoXHs9gGLDN2J1lziCan7XnoNiCutN8jZIsr2IrD4uzK0eGwG%2FROBx2Clq7zY0Yij0W5aXUqn7keKqWJrJhw9MllLCV1rNJpkEEHt0AT%2B8OEecY%2Fu8Uy%2BBpCbCnERcj7rGCJPoqz%2FudROlXbMqigRnDbBpSYH4FIPMpqGj7PNsOgz2tYutIYxpbUXuYpR3I3FU3BrTWbwRgEq6a3H6%2FMvNTWzetwOwFhJzJoeTj0AcXYulg%2BOI7RmQ%2FKAVSAR%2FrALFMYlS1d32qMyPdILD1QnPIaQiNAnk%2FcpwrwXxQM2aNFJKy%2BTVUv5cYlguhRquu8uySYKDzXDMnUN13oJM0BkYiBCGTHfgwumguK8JAL3KDyWvAcFuaHpqH7mlG31vbCdqSKa6abMzKoDqunaE2Cu0lwXaXI3jELCH8Ezlfd%2B0s6VsdPRD932Kmj1wV9keySOEWLnivHaMNFqzaA7Wvjp2oBfL%2Fxl3zWQ%2FKUQtg8zgVHONMGwP%2BHps3VEQ%2Bwc9l09%2BWsmht8WpJQqX9NY%2BuXrqBXU3Ei1sWi5s%2FK02NaaXASDvwOoGakJwn1ZAeQ0K3DA2IYBJ36Q%2BIUMLT15X7vHPCHvlTB4O5W3R1IwGxuUg%2FWfogyXRVaeJGBGpppIxMWiNQuCKyWruq0eq1fm%2Fc7r4cYhEz1zIp07dxdDuL35jdB11WH62p638Ams5qptkzatBnxlaWl6heraZrv%2B%2BH3pc1XKCHbAbwltndqCnGR8CoQqP26hm0zrFdlwgQ59rSY6J9socVA13verVhzt1OesdmUUYCLF5C2ZEEvByvyhS334WX%2BS0vOHrx8zbqmo9peufjod83Ai%2FvhYcNC9g2h5B2CLdb%2FExYP7RRWpgJ2UuAUEuUBV97bTx9nneVaBK8GsIDI7RbJQqs03fDI%2B3bvuTv6EsFlBXfb6xNDYBQ3GElkZ3x5y9NnM%2FplkH00RtYX31ECg3kkZue%2BfwEd226dsj9wO81oq4rqIPgbx91Aou%2BUeRPXarL1nXzNs4THtxTSXIEye%2FXpqb%2BhnS8viwbGp7OfZ%2B32wUPd8IO1GWia0A116Y%2F2bAfkRAGo93tgaRw7yDdvdsyRJScXi%2BAiHC3gW6WEagRMigR2nbYgeOIaq7x%2FayZfG%2BfuHQluznsWKbsp%2Bbm%2FQ6Ho3YuAVRTpnda2%2FFn8Nv4rV7O4ydDUNQnb3%2BBuP0xHyRnMG8hyVRLKO3zt0l7hiN8g5VxoBfYrSGbst89njYC1OSJRnTczvMEzEWeOtnBNIQOwup7mwfPWJqxR7F3KG%2B5zTse0kOqLDoi9FJEuaiHkBEZvv8w7yF4kBvMD5lDvHBIHowCbCPvTIt7wcVIgMu56Nf88mL7tmbVfkENY0esB8%2F7jpo%2FfDwbO0SvyASoFa9v0pZYnfN2qsaGTwA8S7ich%2B1uXe2hZgtrqdshjC65cJuFqIaIUWQ6qCi8Y7XhRrtudOGn62nWOgD4v2e2sV6tqaIO8I5EQRjfTPWT06QqaLrHPAyOb%2BD8lj79NwqQDbvV6Zn02cdsuSVyWMo%2F8MdVujIefVV7vVewYXT7rnkrAZ8bigDQAesNVTQWYPjqqsx%2Bnf7AbXp9BS1QBorxLNBwAZOH4vgZzgrUI33Ob6B%2FFAFZBZwFMREHG5aZmh3AxWu5CGHHACvgwwi6aaerLIIQBClFq%2FTF43IDLSX5jc2AandiBnqb372LHP3B8ker10BE1eSBpNg%2FngMFvZeEal1pVR1TTLQJQwswil5u%2F%2B8LL9s6QQkasrfWkOxto2GozyiESBfBW%2BmfxEndlNLG41EbudH7R0EUMS3W7pGYCoQE31EqkW721DMDviefRxAI%2FnJubzRD3iDbyi%2BUwS8ltqs5WzlZPwbkPHHSwOdD45GbmzL%2BsFOLkJsNJUf6htkwekq%2BvcTWPMWYN0c3RhibLgBCNZq3Ii9p6BclC%2BhppO8tr5nLVqY8iSt8gjrEhCdVGvtwh0Qf7o57JiiqIsRCIDXkyiQFcwKxeQlMQITfmxqi3Q8ecV7Zldtf48Ix3xuMeJbQmOwgfByl8l4e8eQ9TumgJXMvrleqnHQ7Uz440Sm19zLnwMmY6nJMjIb647aiVR%2F7BMGJBdglYeKt9jBaQaBqc%2F3nulIh68mGK%2BGTYAGEPCtrzhfMzwSwZiGLaXyQ3BcxHpwJESrpxVElOOdtsc20x9fD34h9vYHfIp71JH%2B7EguvbzBUEmY5f8u2qnH3gpf%2FbU3Zg1nZ2LQm3%2Fg6cCaUiI5wZ%2FQkKBsOu%2FSvtcsxFj4lUtRb13ZhMjF4m%2BsW%2F9SAzwo4p6JCl%2Fb9MpS2eEjseflSavU862WpDvJtjoi%2FpkidpoJcavuzJUf%2BTP7LA%2F9DgcYSIXsz2BJ9G2uU5114oe%2FlVlDxgJk6QHF72SZGt9Wnw9rHPzfevD7KGwfgW4lcrLYyDxra1AS13zbe41vUe%2Bgd6GMP4TMejFq9QXh8n8TebWPT0%2FbjabP%2FD97crvES70V4XvWutB%2BNgOxGqXyZ8iqqRJZvef9Rd07wJ6T%2BjYk9f%2BPegy5SvQPQjWn5fzEpgf3%2B5CAxYPWIicrtxrMUWCEyicVeqbh%2FScV2wCEmZZbmMPJgAdQ3CmMBOxCgIAHheuHRjug3F8J35WWQAfWEfIjB%2FwEupWKEeKP7Y83TpAmvUGlNqF055udHp6uNt%2BhpzFRTOkwEbWYQ%2B%2BH8ltndIlLxLx6SI7TKWWVLyy%2F1Ft7EleYXT6CmFsQE5sjM5tbaRF4aUMlX%2BSCewSAr%2Bx6Akeul8c6J1w4Q8Upt0RHsqQmA0Y%2BZuiL34rxFE%2B%2BKQ3lfROlmcAZ1vVyhZHbiVeId68UaVB9PFX%2BjN%2Bul5LR4Nixb7Z95dciSonZJf%2BNUNhaNIHdjacWABo5cvYr2SN2HKWoXgq9MDTgjz7MDBiWvZxHYi2XftjOn70l84u9e8jwZKOnxykIGZd0SMd%2F%2BS7nliMWms6vBOWSrSU8OxdW7BdxohgZSNZi76SrmlPVK2qt3uH5l71ZVMGrKl9RqKWvuoWBW8NRjSYQTqQ6sWyhNvqY%2FcLrMPt7k4Ppsvfd8CwJZIXWYQhVWYtHX%2FqueunvE2yiSDe86QoAavxXRnXgB1wl8rtB35qaEe2DGgcoeS%2BYpqZ%2F9NhQf58rHEk2OkLrIfWCatjXSByXSIWI5vyd043kl1XftKXs1d6wYqzJENtWsBCa3y2v5TYnMaMAvhtI7m9JrpW0O2dAvQFOk5fjjeR9qNlu2FnuP283%2FHlPDji2oNtGyOcUXENeTfQ%2BuItu2mtc%2Fj7o8FQ0%2Bd1%2FeQNB0ACeqUzUON6WRGtQkf2tlYgrmviQWt5p5CBI8FXiiTbp4N3CtDcoKGpDY8bzLUT8%2FtbzlHZqmkhjajZo6mJAzswBkGeBgSw%2B%2F3nH%2F%2F6W%2F%2F%2BHw%3D%3D'))));
```

Can anyone tell me what it's supposed to do??
My instincts say it's just to crash / slow a server.. am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: Take out the `eval` part and see what code it produces.

Comment: As @David suggested http://codepad.viper-7.com/JHGiaO Then you'll need to do the same once again ;-)

Comment: yes I did do that and echoed it - it produces something similar. I did this about 5 times. I don't understand why this is downvoted?? If you know what it does please share??

Comment: It's a pretty obfuscated license check

Comment: Do take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701291/how-to-decode-eval-gzinflate-base64-decode

Comment: This post has probably been downvoted as this question comes up a lot - however it is normally malicious code inserted into an insecure WordPress installation, and that does not seem to apply here. If you search for "php eval" on Stack Overflow you should find a few duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! I did keep echoing it on my test server but stopped after 5 times. And I did search stackover flow for "gzinflate(base64_decode(rawurldecode(" before posting.. so to all the downvoters - come on what is someone who is trying to learn supposed to do???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's obfuscated the following code :

```
$settings = mysql_query ('select * from settings');
$settingrecord = mysql_fetch_array($settings);
while ($settingrecord = mysql_fetch_array($settings)) {
    $setting[$settingrecord["name"]] = $settingrecord["setting"];
}
$setting['pay_with'] = unserialize($setting['pay_with']);
extract($setting);

function valid_license($license) {
    $domain = str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    $salt = "u3yQjZ14bDKy";
    $hash = substr(base64_encode(sha1($domain.$salt)),0,20);
    return $license == $hash;
}


if(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "admin/") AND session_is_registered("alogin")) {
    if(!valid_license($license_key)) {

        $_POST['license'] = trim($_POST['license']);

        if($_POST['license'] AND valid_license($_POST['license'])) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET setting='".$_POST['license']."' WHERE name='license_key'");
        } else {
            include "../header.php";
            include "../style.php";

            echo "<br /><br />";
            if($_POST['license']!="") echo "<font color=red><b>Please enter a valid license to access the admin area</b></font><br />";
            else echo "Please enter a valid license to access the admin area<br />";

            echo "<form method=post><input type=text name=license size=30 /><br /><input type=submit value=Submit /></form><br />";
            include "../footer.php";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't look malicious at first glance. Looks like it's trying to enforce some kind of licensing or something.

Comment: How many times was it obfuscated? I have tried to de-obfuscate it several times and then gave up :) Just curious.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question :)

Comment: Thanks! For anyone facing this in the future - you can use this website to decode: http://ddecode.com/phpdecoder/

Comment: obfuscated 15 times. I found that out manually copy / pasting + echoing :P